# In asp.net mvc3 Chart helper not showing the master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I am trying to use Chart Helper in ASP.NET MVC3. But problem i am facing is,only the concerned chart is displayed without the master page.

My code is :

**Controller**

```
     public ActionResult Chart()
            {
                Chart chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                       .AddTitle("Chart")
                    .AddSeries(
                    chartType: "line",
                    legend: "Rainfall",
                    xValue: new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" },
                    yValues: new[] { "20", "20", "40", "10", "10" }).AddSeries(chartType: "line", yValues: new[] { "30", "40", "50", "60", "70" }).Write("png");

                return null;

            }
```

**View**

```
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Chart</h2>
<h2>About</h2>
<p><img src="@Url.Action("Chart")" alt="hello chart" /></p>
```

Please help me to find where i am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the chart as an image. Try this:

```
 public ActionResult Chart()
        {
            Chart chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                   .AddTitle("Chart")
                .AddSeries(
                chartType: "line",
                legend: "Rainfall",
                xValue: new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" },
                yValues: new[] { "20", "20", "40", "10", "10" }).AddSeries(chartType: "line", yValues: new[] { "30", "40", "50", "60", "70" })
        .GetBytes("png");


            return File(chart, "image/png");

        }
```

Comment: I am trying to pass values in Url action like @Url.Action("Chart",new {id=ViewBag.Value}) But its not working and not redirecting me to the chart with this value. Please help how this is possible

Comment: Have you added the id parameter to the `Chart()` method? `public ActionResult Chart(int id)`

Comment: @levelnis It says "Cannot implicitly convert byte[] to Chart".